# Floating point exception (core dumped)/ segmentation fault(core dump) due to a int that is 20mb long

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
a = sbrk(20*1024*1024+8192);
        a=(int *)((((int)a>>13)<<13)+8192);
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    ARRAY_SIZE = 20*1024*1024+8192;
    for (times=0; times<SOME_LARGE_NUMBER; times++){
            for (i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i=i+SOME_ACCESS_SIZE){
                         dummy=a[i];
                 }
    }
```

Apparently I get a Floating point exception to the above code it is because of the ARRAY_SIZE 
is 20mb, how do I not get a seg fault or a floating point exception but still have that size of 20mb.

Comment: I did not understand `a=(int *)((((int)a>>13)<<13)+8192);` and you are acessing this point to int as array in `dummy=a[i]` possible cause to seg fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems:

- You have not shown how `a` is declared, so we do not know its type and cannot analyze how expressions involving it are evaluated.
- `sbrk` is an antiquated call. Except in special situations, `malloc` should be used instead.
- The statement `a=(int *)((((int)a>>13)<<13)+8192);` attempts to align `a` to a multiple of 8192 bytes, but it ought to, at least, use `uintptr_t` rather than `int`.
- The argument to `sbrk` is a number of bytes, but the `(int *)` cast suggests `a` is a pointer to `int`. In any case, you should multiply the allocation by `sizeof *a`.
- After `a` has been aligned to a multiple of 8192 bytes, there are no longer `20*1024*1024+8192` bytes available after it, because some of them have been used for the alignment. Yet `ARRAY_SIZE` is set to `20*1024*1024+8192` and used in the loop, thus assuring that the array will be overrun. Possibly, `ARRAY_SIZE` should be set to `20*1024*1024`.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating a block of memory that is `20*1024*1024+8192` **bytes** long and then treating it as an array of `20*1024*1024+8192` **ints**. Try the following instead:

```
ARRAY_SIZE = (20*1024*1024+8192) / sizeof(int);
```